# Can i disable Xceed DoubleUpDown control arrows?

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

Can i disable (it should be not visible) `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DoubleUpDown` control arrows?
It must be look line TextBox, but works only with digits.

I use `AllowSpin=False`, but it only disable spin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `ShowButtonSpinner` property to `false`.